# Python Web Scraping does not load every link from Google Search

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote a program which sends a query to google which only filters out linkedin profiles (on that part everything is working) ... now the problem that I have is that I can't get it to work to give me all the links from a certain search request. It only gives me 9 Linkedin links into my Excel file and then moves onto the next search query. So that's that main thing.

Beyond that my code is also missing a time delay to load the new sections ... but when I entered some sort of time.sleep() it crushed the entire thing...
My Chrome has autoscrolling enabled. After a certain amount of links (manually scrolling down) however, it gives me some sort of message that only the first 226 results were shown to only
Then I had problems with Recaptcha obviously so hope this can be bypassed with some sort of delay functionality..

So I can't solve these things. The rest is working, however.

Here is the relevant section of the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Initialize WebDriver
chromedriver_path = 'C:\\Path\\to\\chromedriver.exe'  # Update this path
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# Base URL for search queries
base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="

# Sample DataFrame to mimic niches_df structure
niches_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Industry': ['Tech', 'Healthcare'],
    'Sub-Industry Keywords': ['Software,Hardware', 'Pharma,Biotech']
})

# Lists of search criteria
countries = ["United States"]
job_titles = ["CEO", "COO", "Founder", "President", "Director"]

# Function to create search query
def create_search_query(sub_industry_keywords, job_titles, country):
    keywords_query = " OR ".join([f'"{keyword}"' for keyword in sub_industry_keywords.split(',')])
    job_titles_query = " OR ".join([f'"{job}"' for job in job_titles])
    return f'site:linkedin.com/in/ ({keywords_query}) AND ({job_titles_query}) AND "{country}"'

collected_links = []

# Iterating through DataFrame rows
for index, row in niches_df.iterrows():
    industry = row['Industry']
    for sub_industry_keywords in row['Sub-Industry Keywords'].split(','):
        search_query = create_search_query(sub_industry_keywords, job_titles, countries[0])
        encoded_search_query = quote_plus(search_query)
        final_search_url = base_url + encoded_search_query

        driver.get(final_search_url)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'linkedin.com/in/')]"))
            )
            links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'linkedin.com/in/')]")
            for link in links:
                href = link.get_attribute('href')
                collected_links.append([href, industry, sub_industry_keywords, ', '.join(countries), ', '.join(job_titles)])
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more results found or timeout reached.")

# Close WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your question is full of statements like "it didn't work" and "I had problems".  That is not enough detail for us to actually help.  Please show us a **complete** code example (not just a relevant section), show us the **actual exact results** of the code, and then **explain** how those results weren't what you wanted.

Comment: And please don't complicate the issue with side details like writing to an excel file.  Your code example should stick to the **core issue** only.  If your real code does extra things like writing to an excel file, then we expect you to make a simplified version of the code that **only** demonstrates the key problem.

Comment: I edited it as simplified as possible.

Comment: Great!  Now show us the actual results from this code, and explain how those results weren't what you expected.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get data off LinkedIn, but you're going based off Google search results. That's an extra layer of bot detection you have to pass through, and a strong one. You might be better off finding a way to get your data directly from LinkedIn. Use rotating proxies if you aren't already.